# i keep getting error while trying to use UK date format

Tags: python, date

i keep getting this error message: time data '28-08-2019' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

here is my code: df_air['TICKET_DEPARTURE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_air['TICKET_DEPARTURE_DATE'].apply(str), format = 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Comment: Could you post your code and the full error please?

Comment: Your format says `/`. Your string is using `-`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for given time is: `%d-%m-%Y`